# Alsa configuration on Raspbian

Tags: configuration, raspberry-pi, raspbian, alsa

I am trying to configure the Alsa Sound to Raspbian. I ran all the commands but when I tried "speaker-test" I got the following error:

```
root@raspberrypi://home/pi# speaker-test

speaker-test 1.0.28

Playback device is default
Stream parameters are 48000Hz, S16_LE, 1 channels
Using 16 octaves of pink noise
Channels count (1) not available for playbacks: Invalid argument
Setting of hwparams failed: Invalid argument
```

Can anybody help?

Comment: Sometimes you can get more luck at [raspberrypi.stackexchange.com](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com) with questions related to Raspberry Pi

Answer (score 0):

Hi try to install the package pavucontrol and test manually opened the program audio settings by clicking test button.

```
sudo apt-get install pavucontrol
```